# javascript: вставка данных в цикле в созданный див

Tags: javascript, html5

Так, в цикле создаёт четыре дива, но не вносит в них тестовые данные, например, i :

```
for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

   document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += '<div id="d0'+(j+1)+'" style ="font-size:12px; color:brown;"></div>';


   for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

      document.getElementById('"d0'+(j+1)+'"').innerHTML += i;
   }
}
```

возможно, тут криво: **('"d0'+(j+1)+'"')** подскажите, плиз, как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
document.getElementById('d0' + (j + 1)).innerHTML += i;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function addDivs() {
  const div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0] ;
  for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
   const divCh = document.createElement("div");
    divCh.id = `d0${j}`;
    divCh.style.fontSize = '12px';
    divCh.style.color = 'brown';
    let iter = '';
    for (let i = 0; i <2; i++) {
      iter += i;
    }
    divCh.innerHTML = iter;
    div.appendChild(divCh);
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, да в проекте будет вставка *по правилам*, я понял свой косяк, тестил идею ..