# вставить список однотипных элементов в div на чистом js

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

При нажатии на кнопку получаются данные из бекенда, в размере 10 штук однотипных объектов. Мне нужно как-то на чистом js насоздавать div конструкций, куда будут помещены пришедшие данные, и вывести это все в нужный div на страницу, как можно это сделать?

Comment: Возможно [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1450953/1450959#1450959) вам подойдет или [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1480492/1480506#1480506). А вот тут есть примеры, как делать [фукнции под однотипные теги](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1493663/)

Comment: пришедшие_данные.forEach(function (el){
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.classList.add("класс");
  div.insertAjansetHTML("куда вставить", el)
})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как-то на чистом js насоздавать div конструкций, куда будут помещены пришедшие данные, и вывести это все в нужный div на страницу, как можно это сделать?

Как некая иллюстрация к вопросу - такой вот пример.

```js
const a = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Вася'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Оля'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Петя'},
]

const od = document.querySelector('div')
a.forEach(o => {
  op = document.createElement('p')
  op.textContent = o.name
  od.append(op)
})
```

```html
<div></div>
```